# Services or Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alert, accelerometer

I am developing an android application where it generates an alert dialog box by detecting shaking.
I want to run that application in background so that whenever we shake the phone the application will automatically opens alert the dialog box.

I am facing problem on the point that where should I put the module of shaking.

I have put that module in the StartCammand() but it didnot work..

Is it possible to implement my application by using BroadcastReceiver?

Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Here is the module that will generate an alert dialog box on detecting Shaking

```
public void onShake(float force) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Shake.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm your condition");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you OK?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Take Care!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Emergency will be reached",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Here I have put the code of Shake in StartCommand()

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
            SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){
            private long now=0;
            private long timeDiff=0;
            private long lastUpdate=0;
            private long lastShake=0;
            private float x=0;
            private float y=0;
            private float z=0;
            private float lastX=0;
            private float lastY=0;
            private float lastZ=0;
            private float force=0;
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){}
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
            {
                now=event.timestamp;
                x=event.values[0];
                y=event.values[1];
                z=event.values[2];
                if(lastUpdate==0)
                {
                    lastUpdate=now;
                    lastShake=now;
                    lastX=x;
                    lastY=y;
                    lastZ=z;
                    Toast.makeText(aContext, "No motion is detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
               {
                    timeDiff=now-lastUpdate;
                    if(timeDiff>0)
                    {
                        force=Math.abs(x+y+z-lastX-lastY-lastZ);
                        if(Float.compare(force, threshold)>0)
                        {
                            if(now-lastShake>=interval)
                            {
                                listener.onShake(force);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(aContext, "no motion is detected",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            lastShake=now;
                        }
                        lastX=x;
                        lastY=y;
                        lastZ=z;
                        lastUpdate=now;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(aContext, "no motion is detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                listener.onAccelerometerChanged(x,y,z);
            }

        };
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: When do you call Context.startService() on the service?

Comment: @NathanielD.WaggonerI call it in the MainActivity class where I pass the Intent to direct to the Activity that extends Service

Comment: See answer.  You're not registering the listener you have set up.

Comment: Just to point out - you instantiate a listener in this code, but you never register it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a text book example of a Service.

Why?

1)  You want it to run in the background
2)  Presumably you want it to continue running even if the user backs out of your app.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

It looks to me like you're not registering the Listener in this case... see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor

Specifically:

```
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
```

If you instead move the relevant register/unregister calls into the appropriate locations in your service this should resolve itself.

You can set the type of sensor etc... accordingly.

Using a service does complicate the presentation of the Dialog however, and you may want to present more information on your specific use case before you make the final determination of which to use.

Comment: I have registered in SensorListener..When i am running this application without running in background ,it works fine but when I want it to run in Background,it didnot run.I have extends it with Service but it didnot work.